# Regex pattern query to match text within string

Tags: regex

I have a large xml file with rows of :

```
<level id="100" name="blaha blah blah" currency="USD" abbr="blh">
```

I need regex to find "blaha blah blah"

Any ideas?

Comment: regex is quicker in this case.

Comment: regex `/blaha blah blah/` will do what you want.

Comment: It might be quicker, but it will be more difficult to write and understand.

Comment: the text is different on each line

Comment: I just need to do a quick search & replace.  Trying to learn regex too !

Comment: @user2497790 if the text will be different on each line is there some pattern to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the regex has to match *only* the `blah blah blah`, you can use:

```
(?<=<level[^>]*\bname\s*=\s*").+?(?=")
```

Otherwise, I would recommend that you use something like:

```
<level[^>]*\bname\s*=\s*"(.+?)"
```

The value will end up as the first group in the match.

Here, lazy quantifiers are absolutely necessary, because otherwise it will match everything up to the last quote mark on the line (or in the file, if dot matches line breaks too) rather than just to the next quote mark.

Comment: Almost there with (?<=name=").+?" I just need to ignore the last quote

Comment: You can add `<level[^>]*` at the beginning of the regex to limit to `level` tags, if not will will match the value of `name` attributes of any tag (eg. `<lol name="bal bla bla">`)

Answer (score 0):

As others have written, Regex is **NOT** meant for this case, and if you're looking for a robust solution, an XML parser is the way to go. For quick and dirty though, this will work:

```
\sname\s*=\s*""(.*?)""
```

This matches the following:

```
<level id="100" name="blaha blah blah" currency="USD" abbr="blh">
<level id="100" name ="blaha blah blah" currency="USD" abbr="blh">
<level id="100" name= "blaha blah blah" currency="USD" abbr="blh">
<level id="100" name  =  "blaha blah blah" currency="USD" abbr="blh">
```

Comment: No joy with \sname\s*=\s*""(.*?)""

Comment: I'm nearly there with : name="([^\"]*)  I just need to get rid ogf the name="